# Reading multiple files from FileChooserDialog GTK 3

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am trying to open a `Gtkmm::FileChooserDialog` to choose multiple files and print their paths along with filenames to a label. I can open the dialog and choose the files but I am having a hard time reading the filenames to my variables.

```cpp
      FileChooserDialog openFileDialog("", FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN);
      openFileDialog.add_button("Cancel", RESPONSE_CANCEL);
      openFileDialog.add_button("Open", RESPONSE_OK);
      openFileDialog.set_current_folder(ustring::compose("%1/Desktop", ustring(getenv("HOME"))));
      openFileDialog.set_transient_for(*this);
      openFileDialog.set_select_multiple(true);
      Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::FileFilter> fileFilter = Gtk::FileFilter::create();
      fileFilter->set_name("Text Files (*.txt)");
      fileFilter->add_pattern("*.txt");
      openFileDialog.add_filter(fileFilter);
      fileFilter = Gtk::FileFilter::create();
      fileFilter->set_name("All Files (*.*)");
      fileFilter->add_pattern("*.*");
      openFileDialog.add_filter(fileFilter);
      
      if (openFileDialog.run() == RESPONSE_OK)
        label.set_text(ustring::compose("File = %1", ustring(openFileDialog.get_filename())));
      return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Gtk::FileChooser::get_filenames`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1FileChooser.html#a71bbd79a36b8fb445b6d735345233a27) (Gtkmm 3.24):

```cpp
if (openFileDialog.run() == Gtk::RESPONSE_OK)
{
  for(const auto& fileName : openFileDialog.get_filenames())
  {
    label.set_text(Glib::ustring::compose("File = %1", Glib::ustring(fileName)));
  }
}
```

which returns a `std::vector` of file names.

**Note:** In my answer, I keep overwriting the `label` variable because it was all the context there was in your code snippet. My be you have multiple labels or you want to pack all the file names somehow in a single label. I let this part to you.